# Node Js API : where the undefined comes from?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I write this code to get the array from url. this is the url : http://localhost:3000/main?a=aaa.jpg&a=bbb.jpg

And here is the code :

```
//Define module
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const { exec } = require('child_process');

//extract function
function extract (req,res,next){
    res.write(`filename : ${req.query.a}`); //kt page
    console.log(req.query.a);//kt terminal
    next();
};

//main function
function main (req,res,next){
    res.write('\nkuor dok \n');
    res.end();
};

app.use(extract);
app.get('/main',main);
app.listen(3000);
```

This is the output in terminal.

```
Array(2) ["aaa.jpg", "bbb.jpg"]
undefined
```

The question is where the **undefined** comes from? It affected everything i need to do. The array is perfectly fine. But suddenly undefined comes out. Can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I pasted the same code and it doesn't gives me undefined expect the fact when the program starts it return undefined as there is nothing in `req.query`

Comment: Thanks for the response. this is so weird . I will try to rewrite it again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you provided above and i got only the array in the terminal

```
[ 'aaa.jpg', 'bbb.jpg' ]
```

When i tried the url in the browser i got

```
filename : aaa.jpg,bbb.jpg
kuor dok
```

as the output. i didn't get any undefined

Comment: thanks for the response.it works before this exactly just like this. and then suddenly undefined comes out. maybe i should rewrite it back

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to define extract function as a middleware. It will be executed for every request

try to comment app.get:

```
app.use(extract);
//app.get('/main', main);
app.listen(3000);
```

Then try to make the request

```
GET: http://localhost:3000/main?a=aaa.jpg&a=bbb.jpg
```

you will get

```
[ 'aaa.jpg', 'bbb.jpg' ]
```

You are handling the request twice. First by the global middleware, the second time by **app.get()** that calls also the middleware **extract** before **main**

As I see app.get don't handle your query params and you got **undefined** due to an empty  object try to log: req.query intead of req.query.q

```
function extract(req, res, next) {
    res.write(`filename : ${req.query.a}`); //kt page
    console.log(req.query); //kt terminal
    next();
};
```